# Conditional String Match R Character Vector Collapse Select Elements

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning, stringr

I have a character vector where I'd like to match a specific string and then collapse the element containing that string match **only** with the next element in the character vector and then allow the process to continue until the character vector ends.  For example just one situation:

```
'"FundSponsor:Blackrock Advisors" "Category:"  "Tax-Free Income-Pennsylvania"  "Ticker:"  "MPA" "NAV Ticker:" "XMPAX"                          "Average Daily Volume (shares):" "26,000"                         "Average Daily Volume (USD):"    "$0.335M"                        "Inception Date:"  "10/30/1992" "Inception Share Price:" "$15.00"                         "Inception NAV:" "$14.18" "Tender Offer:" "No"                             "Term:" "No"'
```

Combining each element containing a `:` with only the element following it would be great BUT I've struggled with using the paste function because it just generally collapses the entire vector based on the `:` into one element which is not the more targeted solution I'm looking for.

Here's an example of what I'd like a portion of the revised output to look like:

```
"Inception Share Price:$15.00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that might help:

First split using `strsplit`, then bind elements that belong together

```
# split the string
vec <- unlist(strsplit(string, '(?=\")(?=\")', perl = TRUE))
vec <- vec[! vec %in% c(' ', '\"')]
# that's how vec looks like right now
head(vec)
# [1] "FundSponsor:Blackrock Advisors" "Category:"                      "Tax-Free Income-Pennsylvania"   "Ticker:"                        "MPA"                           
# [6] "NAV Ticker:"    
#
# now paste the elements
ind <- grepl(':.+',vec)
tmp <- vec[!ind]
vec[!ind] <- paste0(tmp[seq(1,length(tmp),2)], tmp[seq(2,length(tmp),2)])
head(vec)
# [1] "FundSponsor:Blackrock Advisors"        "Category:Tax-Free Income-Pennsylvania" "Ticker:MPA"                            "NAV Ticker:XMPAX"                     
# [5] "Average Daily Volume (shares):26,000"  "Average Daily Volume (USD):$0.335M"
```

with the data

```
string = "\"FundSponsor:Blackrock Advisors\" \"Category:\" \"Tax-Free Income-Pennsylvania\" \"Ticker:\" \"MPA\" \"NAV Ticker:\" \"XMPAX\" \"Average Daily Volume (shares):\" \"26,000\" \"Average Daily Volume (USD):\" \"$0.335M\" \"Inception Date:\" \"10/30/1992\" \"Inception Share Price:\" \"$15.00\" \"Inception NAV:\" \"$14.18\" \"Tender Offer:\" \"No\" \"Term:\" \"No\""
```

**Explanation**

- The `regex` `(?=\")(?=\")` basically tells `R` to split the string whenever there are two `\"`. The syntax `(?!*something*)` means `*something*` comes before/after. So the above simply reads: *split the string at every position that is preceeded by a `\"` and that preceeds a `\"`*.
- The `strsplit(...)` above creates elements of the form `\"` and  (`'\"Category:\" \"...'` becomes the vector `'\"';'Category:';'\"';' ';'...'`). So by using `! vec %in% c(...)` we remove those unwanted elements.

**Addendum**

If elements of the form `"string:"` followed by a `" "` are contained, in the above code remove the line `vec <- vec[! vec %in% c(' ', '\"')]` and add the lines

```
vec <- vec[seq(2L, length(vec), 4L)]
vec[vec == ' '] <- NA_character_
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.  Thanks very much.  Could you explain the syntax you used in the unlist(strsplit) portion?  Specifically, this:                 (?=\")(?=\") and this vec[! vec %in% c(' ', '\"')].

Comment: @js80 I've added a short explanation

Comment: I am getting this error message now because there were some edge cases where the solution you provided didn't combine the elements: Warning message:
In vec[!ind] <- paste0(tmp[seq(1, length(tmp), 2)], tmp[seq(2, length(tmp),  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length           Any idea what the issue could be?  Printing the vector up until that point works without issue?

Comment: "tmp" is shorter than "ind" because the first two elements are already correctly formatted with the ":" followed by related text in tmp.  Not sure how that happened since printing the vector looks the same.

Comment: Hey Nate, a follow up question but after you've filtered down the elements in the vector containing either blanks or string with a colon followed no string, how would you replace only those blank elements after the string with the colon with an NA (if they happen to be blank) otherwise collapsing the contents as previously.  Trying to control for missing values which has been hard.  Thanks!

Comment: @js80 I'm having difficulties understanding the issue. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure of course.  Thank you again for your help.  I have the same vector you saw but here is an example: "Average Daily Volume (shares):"  is followed by a blank because the data was missing in the scrape.  The script you provided is great but in this situation it still collapses the element when an NA would probably be best.  The result is that it disrupts the structure of the vector elements following missing data like this.  See for example:  "MInception Date:11/25/1986Inception Share Price:"

Comment: I realize it's an edge case but the overall table is quite large and I'm concerned not having a dynamic solution like the one you provided which also deals with blanks as NA's could introduce a disruption when trying to create the table.  Again, thank you very much.

Comment: To say any strings containing a colon should be collapsed with the following element is probably a good rule but I would imagine first recording an NA for the element with the blank would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want the outcome to be one single key: value format or if you just want to clean that long string and have it in the following format key1: value1 key2: value2 key3: value3. If this is the case, you can achieve it via the following code:

```
char = '"FundSponsor:Blackrock Advisors" "Category:" "Tax-Free Income-Pennsylvania" "Ticker:" "MPA" "NAV Ticker:" "XMPAX" "Average Daily Volume (shares):" "26,000" "Average Daily Volume (USD):" "$0.335M" "Inception Date:" "10/30/1992" "Inception Share Price:" "$15.00" "Inception NAV:" "$14.18" "Tender Offer:" "No" "Term:" "No"'

char_tidy = gsub('\\" \\"', " ", char)

# output is below
> char_tidy
[1] "\"FundSponsor:Blackrock Advisors Category: Tax-Free Income-Pennsylvania Ticker: MPA NAV Ticker: XMPAX Average Daily Volume (shares): 26,000 Average Daily Volume (USD): $0.335M Inception Date: 10/30/1992 Inception Share Price: $15.00 Inception NAV: $14.18 Tender Offer: No Term: No\""
```